# tqdm prints an empty bar after loop ends

Tags: tqdm

tqdm prints an empty bar after loop ends. I tried implementing this [solution](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+tqdm+prints+another+empty+bar), but with no success.

The problem does not exist if I remove the print statement (see code).

My code is:

```
for PhotoIdx in tqdm(range(Nphotos), position=0, leave=True):
    .... 
end
print("something")
return x
```

I attach a photo with what is outputted to the terminal (the third bar is from another python file).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a Pycharm issue, which can be fixed by editing the Run/Debug Configuration in Pycharm and checking the box that says "Emulate terminal in output console"

[image]

The standard output terminal appears to have trouble with properly outputting  text applications that use certain terminal features, although I don't know the exact cause of this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a bug from Pycharm.
It's working fine inside the terminal.
Have a good day

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).